# After migration from 2010, sites are broken (icons, pictures, content editors)

Tags: migration, content-editor-web-part

I remember being able to fix this through SharePoint Designer.

I removed one chunk of codes and everything went back to normal, which I cannot recall how to do it at this moment.

I will provide the pictures below!

[image]

Above is the broken top navigation bar and on the right, the picture turned into a bunch of random icons.

[image]

Above is a broken content editor...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After migration, it seems like the master page was broken.

Just swapped out the broken master page link, in SharePoint Designer, to new working master page.